# g++ error stringop-overflow on a simple copy of an std::vector

Tags: c++, gcc, g++

The following simple c++ code doesn't compile with g++ if I use any `-O` flag. I can't understand why.

Minimum and reproducible example:

```cpp
#include <vector>

using A = std::vector<size_t>;
A foo(const A& a)
{
    if (a.size() < 2)
        return a;
    return {};
}

int main()
{
    A obj;
    foo(obj);
}
```

Compilation flags: `-Ofast -Werror`

You can test on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/788q4bbK7) with GCC 13.2.0 for full compiler output.
Relevant compilation error:

```
/opt/compiler-explorer/arm/gcc-trunk-20240202/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/include/c++/14.0.1/bits/stl_algobase.h:438:30: error: 'void* __builtin_memmove(void*, const void*, unsigned int)' writing between 5 and 2147483647 bytes into a region of size 4 overflows the destination [-Werror=stringop-overflow=]
  438 |             __builtin_memmove(__result, __first, sizeof(_Tp) * _Num);
      |             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: Looks like a regression, gcc 12 works fine: https://godbolt.org/z/sff7sf7Wo. You should report a bug to them.

Comment: feel free to report please, as I have never done that before

Comment: All is wrong. There is no move. There is no bug. Something is borked in your environment would be my guess.

Comment: I imagined it could be something on my environment, which is why I also tested on vms and godbolt

Comment: Weird. without the `if (a.size() < 2)` or even with `if (a.size() < 1)` or `if (a.size() < 3)` things seem to work out.

Comment: How does a bug so drastic like this passes unnoticed on 13.2.0?

Comment: "Compilation flags: -Ofast" - Be *very* careful with `-Ofast` (or just don't use it), it allows `gcc` to break some rules of the C++ standard to make things fast, but that can also silently give you wrong results and compared to `-O3` it doesn't really buy you much. Personally I prefer correct code over fast code (slightly) with subtle gotchas.

Comment: @JesperJuhl same result in `O3`.

Comment: Yes, I said in the question "if I use any `-O` flag"

Comment: How did it get missed? return by value of a const reference inside `if (a.size() < 2)` is pretty specific. Easy to miss.

Comment: @user4581301 I didn't say there would be any difference for *this* code, just that `-Ofast` is *dangerous* in general.

Comment: Has there been a result different from the "as-if" rule?

Comment: @user4581301 true. I have to give you that. lol. I hadn't noticed it only worked with the number 2

Comment: Assembly is subtly different: https://godbolt.org/z/nnrTM3hfb . Times like this I wish I'd spent more time on Intel assembly than I did on Motorola.

Comment: Seems to still behave correctly: https://godbolt.org/z/rqezPfjoE

Comment: In proper heisenbug form, the warning goes away when you turn on the sanitizer.

Comment: Maybe related: https://www.phoronix.com/news/Linux-Drop-GCC--Wstringop-of

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a [gcc bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=100366):

[spurious warning - std::vector::clear followed by std::vector::insert(vec.end(), ...) with -O2](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=100366)

[incorrect warning: memcpy writing 1 or more bytes into a region of size 0 overflows the destination with std::vector::insert](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=106199)